# Inner actions are not getting executed inside transaction in slick

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I have requirement where i have to insert into book table and based on auto Id generated , I have to insert into bookModules table.For every bookModule autoincrement Id , I have to insert into bookAssoc table. But bookModule is populated using seq[bookMods] and bookAssociation data is populated using Seq[userModRoles].

I have written below code to achieve this but it is only executing action1. My inner actions are not getting executed. Please help me .

```
val action1 =bookDao.insert(book)

  val action2 = action1.map { id => DBIO.sequence(
      bookMods.map { bookMod => 
        bookModDao.insert(new bookModule(None, id, bookMod.moduleId, bookMod.isActive))
          .map { bookModId =>
            userModRoles.map { userModRole =>
              bookAssocDao.insert(new bookAssociation(None, bookModId, userModRole.moduleId, userModRole.roleId))


            }
          }

      })

    }

 db.run(action2.transactionally)
```

**EDIT 1: Adding code in for comphrension**

```
val action1 = for{
    bookId<-bookDao.insert(book) // db transaction
    bookMod<-bookModules// this is scala collection // Iterate each element and Insert into  tables
    bookModId<-bookModDao.insert(new bookModule(None, bookId, bookMod.moduleId, bookMod.isActive))
    userModRole<-userModRoles //// this is scala collection // Iterate each element and Insert into  tables
    bookAssocDao.insert(new bookAssociation(None, bookModId, userModRole.moduleId, userModRole.roleId))

  }yield()

   db.run(action2.transactionally)
```

Comment: Try to use `for comprehension` instead of it. It will be more readable to check it and probably you can see that you make mistake in code ;)

Comment: @PatrykRudnicki : For comphrension showing me compilation error because i am using for comphrension for iterating over scala collection and creating DB query.

Comment: Yes :) I'll write you answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to split your logic into two parts.

1) DBIO

2) iterates over collections.

In that case, a solution should be easy. But without using for comprehension.

```
bookModules.map{ bookMod =>
    userModRoles.map{ userModRole =>
        db.run(bookDao.insert(book).flatMap{ bookId =>
            bookModDao.inser(new bookModule(None, bookId, bookMod.moduleId, bookMod.isActive)).map{ bookModId =>
                bookAssocDao.insert(new bookAssociation(None, bookModId, userModRole.moduleId, userModRole.roleId))
            }
         }).transactionally
    }
}
```

Try something like this. It should work. You can think about move db.run to Dao classes. And here, probably it's service you should work on Futures.

And sorry if I make some mistake with parenthesis, but here it's difficult to have everything clear :)

Comment: Its showing me compilation error db.run().transactionally .Are we adding transactionally on first insert.

Comment: You can try without transactionally. I don't have your project so I can't run it

Comment: But i want this to do in single transaction.Either everything should be committed or nothing

Comment: currently i  have removed transactionally. There are multiple entries for book table . i think its because we are iterating over bookModules. Also there was no entry for bookAssocDao